# Flatpak: Can't check signature: public key not found

Tags: flatpak

I am using `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`. I installed flatpak from official [documentation of flatpak](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu). Now I am trying to install [bottles](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.usebottles.bottles) by using this command:

```
flatpak install flathub com.usebottles.bottles
```

and I am getting this error:

```
error: Unable to load summary from remote flathub: Signature made Mon 03 Oct 2022 01:12:46 PM PKT using RSA key ID 562702E9E3ED7EE8
Can't check signature: public key not found
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGrKG.png)

I also tried to install other programs with **flatpak** but I got the same error.

These are the other programs I tried to install.

```
# For installing Google Chrome.
flatpak install flathub com.google.Chrome

# For installing discord.
flatpak install flathub com.discordapp.Discord
```

I tried to find about this error about I could not find this error about Flatpak. I have not used any other software or commands. I only used [flatpak documentation commands](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu) and **flatpak installing commands** So, If someone know about this error. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What other program and the exact command you uses would be helpful. Please EDIT the question and add this info.

Comment: I will try this: https://garfnet.org.uk/cms/2022/02/01/flatpak-public-key-error/

Comment: Above link did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I think that the link provided on the flatpak website has not been updated.
I tried:

```shell
flatpak remote-delete --force flathub
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

I could successfully download my applications.
The provided link on Flatpak website for the Ubuntu distribution was:
`https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`